Filling the Space Between a line and a parabola
This is where I'm at right now. I don't know how to fill the area between the line and the parabola though.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=1,yscale=1]

    \draw [<->] (0,5.5) -- (0,0) -- (3.5,0);
    \draw [<->] (0,-6.5) -- (0,0) -- (-5.5,0);
    \draw[help lines] (-5,-6) grid (3,5);
    \draw[blue, ultra thick, domain=-3.1:2.1,<->] plot (\x, {4-\x*\x});
    \draw[red, ultra thick, domain=-3.25:1.5,<->] plot (\x, {2*\x+1});
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SX! I made your code compilable by adding a \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}.

\documentclass[tikz, margin=2pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns, patterns.meta}% needed for lines patterns

% Defining custom colors for flexibility
\colorlet{myFillColor}{orange}
\colorlet{myPrimaryPatternColor}{orange}
\colorlet{mySecondaryPatternColor}{blue}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    % Draw axes and grid
    \draw [<->] (0,5.5) -- (0,0) -- (3.5,0);
    \draw [<->] (0,-6.5) -- (0,0) -- (-4.5,0);
    \draw[help lines] (-4,-6) grid (3,5);
    
    % Clip the area between the parabola and the line from x = -3 to x = 1
    \begin{scope}
        % here lies the magic of TikZ: Define the clipping path along the parabola
        \clip plot[domain=-3:1] (\x, {4 - \x*\x});

        % choose the combination you prefer, examples taken from https://tikz.dev/library-patterns#sec-62.3
        \fill[pattern={north west lines}, pattern color={myPrimaryPatternColor}] (-4,-6) rectangle (3,5);
        % \fill[pattern={Lines[angle=-45, distance={3pt/sqrt(2)}]}, pattern color={mySecondaryPatternColor}] (-4,-6) rectangle (3,5);
        \fill[myFillColor, opacity=0.3] (-4,-6) rectangle (3,5);
    \end{scope}

    % Plot the parabola and the line
    \draw[blue, ultra thick, domain=-3.1:2.1,<->] plot (\x, {4 - \x*\x});
    \draw[red, ultra thick, domain=-3.25:1.5,<->] plot (\x, {2*\x + 1});
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

The \clip command within a scope environment restricts drawing to the area between the functions. We first trace the parabola from x=-3to x=1, establishing the upper boundary. The rectangle command then uses the clipped region as its canvas, filling only between the parabola and the line.


My first try with spath3 (using Qrrbrbirlbel's answer to this post How to color the specific region?)
remark: samples=2 is sufficient for Cred
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{spath3,backgrounds,intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=1,yscale=1]
    \draw [<->] (0,5.5) -- (0,0) -- (3.5,0);
    \draw [<->] (0,-6.5) -- (0,0) -- (-5.5,0);
    \draw[help lines] (-5,-6) grid (3,5);
    \draw[spath/save=Cblue,blue, ultra thick, domain=-3.1:2.1,<->] plot (\x, {4-\x*\x});
    \draw[spath/save=Cred,red, ultra thick, samples=2,domain=-3.25:1.5,<->] plot (\x, {2*\x+1});;
    \scoped[
        on background layer,
        spath/split at intersections={Cblue}{Cred},
        spath/remove components={Cblue}{0},
        ]
    \fill[red!20]
        (spath cs:{Cblue} 0) [spath/use={Cblue}]
                            [spath/use={Cred, reverse}]
        -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


